# Problems making navigation clickable

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, navigation

I am creating a portfolio website, and I have looked through maybe questions on here unable to solve my problem. I have 2 links in my header,  + logo leading home. One link is clickable, the other is not. I am using HTML5:

```
<div id="container">

<div id="top">

    <div class="banner">

    <div id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></div>

    <div id="logo"><a href="index4.html"><img class="logo" src="images/mira-logo.png" alt="mira-logo"></a></div>

    <div id="about"><a href="about.html">about</a></div>

    </div>

</div>

<div id="body"> 
</div>

<div id="footer">    
</div>  


</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#container{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%; 
position: relative;  }

img.logo { 
text-align: center;
padding-top: 0.7%;
width: 18%;
height: 18%; 
position: relative; }

#top {
text-align: center;
background-color:#FFF;
text-decoration: none; }

.banner {
margin-top: 14%;
width: 100%;
background-color:#000000;
height: 28px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
left: 0;
visibility: visible; }

/*Nav Links*/   

#portfolio {
text-align: center;
float: left;
font-family: helvetica, arial;
padding-top: 0.5%;
padding-left: 25%;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
top: 0;
visibility: visible; }

#logo {
text-align: center;
position: fixed;
z-index: 2;
top: 0;
visibility: visible; }

#about {
text-align: center;
float: right;
padding-top: 0.5%;
font-family: helvetica, arial;
padding-right: 25%;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
top: 0;
visibility: visible; }

/**/    

a:link {
font-size: 95%;
display: inline;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF; }

a:hover, a:active {
font-size: 110%;
text-decoration: none;
color: #CCC; }

a:visited {
font-size: 95%;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF; }

/* Body/ Section */ 

#body {
position: fixed;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center; }

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%; }
```

I did have the `a:links` specified to each `div` `#portfolio` as well as `#about` but removed them thinking it would solve this! Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Live example please – http://jsfiddle.net/ or something.

Comment: Closest I could get is http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xeLrt what is the issue - which link are you having issues with?

Comment: "Portfolio" is not clickable, "About" is working fine

Comment: full html with body content: http://cdpn.io/GBrdt

Comment: i feel like it could not be working bc the body div is overlapping the header, how do i get it to align with the bottom of the black bar no matter what size the screen is?

Comment: Can you say what browser are you using? Works fine in Safari 7 and Chrome 33 for Mac OSX.

Comment: http://codepen.io/jellybeandoll/pen/Bewlr

Comment: i am trying on safari and google chrome, i think its when i put my body content in there it over laps

Comment: I can't help you since all examples are working fine here...

Comment: My first guess is to remove the absolute and fixed positioning. The `#body` div should naturally fall below the `#top` div without any special positioning. A live example would be very helpful to diagnose the problem though

Comment: is there a way i can give you a live example?

Comment: I removed a video i had in the body on my page and the "portfolio" and "about" links work fine, but I can't align it under the header